# DropboxSDK.framework is not working for Simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, dropbox

I have included new Dropbox framework into my project its working on real device but its not working for Simulator.Its give me 4 issue as following

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DBRestClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DropboxUploader.o
      objc-class-ref in ImportDropBox.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DocumentListAppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in DocumentListViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in texteditorViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DropboxSettings.o
      objc-class-ref in DropboxUploader.o
      objc-class-ref in ImportDropBox.o
  "_kDBRootAppFolder", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've implemented Dropbox in a project, but if you are using pre-built libraries there might be one for the simulator and one for the device. If this is the case see if Dropbox provides a repository for their framework and add that to your project, then you can avoid having to switch between their simulator lib and their device lib.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add "DropboxSDK.framework" and not "DropboxSDK" to your project's frameworks.